# Writing a toy compiler - call is segfaulting

Tags: x86, compiler-construction, x86-64

This question comes out of me writing a toy compiler, but I don't think that it's necesary to show the compiler side of this question - this is strictly an issue of me not being very experienced with assembly.

I am working on implementing functions into my language. I have generated the following assembly (AT&T) which should print `6`. The program segfaults at `call *%rax`, which I assume means that I'm not saving the address of my function correctly. What should happen is that the function `f0` should read the arguments from the stack, multiply them, and leave the result in `%rax`. The `print` function is just a wrapper around the `printf` function from C to print `%rax`.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and the code was compiled with `gcc test.S -o test.out -no-pie`, in case it matters.

```
.data
numfmt:
.asciz "%d\n"

.text
print:
push %rbx
mov %rax, %rsi
mov $numfmt, %rdi
xor %rax, %rax
call printf
pop %rbx
ret

.globl main
main:
push %rbp
mov %rsp, %rbp
jmp s0
f0:
push %rbp
mov %rsp, %rbp
mov 16(%rbp), %rax
push %rax
mov 8(%rbp), %rax
pop %rcx
imul %rcx, %rax
mov %rbp, %rsp
pop %rbp
ret
s0:
mov $f0, %rax
push %rax
mov $1, %rax
push %rax
mov $2, %rax
push %rax
mov -8(%rbp), %rax
call *%rax
add 16, %rsp
call print
mov $0, %rax
mov %rbp, %rsp
pop %rbp
ret
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mov $f0, %rax`?

Comment: Also, I may have lost count of the pushes, but I don't think you've got 16-byte stack alignment when printf is called.

Comment: 1) Changing that line doesn't fix the problem on it's own, although you may be correct. 2) I believe that the `print` aligns it, but I can't remember where I got that code from, and I might have removed the alignment part a week ago because I didn't realize I needed it for `cdecl` then.

Comment: `print` will maintain proper alignment (that's what `push %rbx` does) if the stack is already aligned correctly when you call it.  But by my count it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AT&T syntax, `mov f0, %rax` is an indirect move: it loads `%rax` with the qword located at address `f0`.  But you want to load the address itself.  That's an immediate move, and so the operand `f0` needs to be prefixed with `$` to indicate that it's immediate.  Thus it should say `mov $f0, %rax`.

For similar reasons, `add 16, %rsp` is wrong as it attempts to add to `%rsp` the value located at address 16.  That page is not mapped hence segfault.  Again, you want `add $16, %rsp`.

Next, in `f0` your frame pointer offsets are wrong.  `16(%rbp)` is the second parameter pushed, not the first, and `8(%rbp)` is the return address.  Don't forget to account for the effect on the stack pointer of the `push %rbp` itself.  So you end up computing 2 times the return address instead of 1 times 2.  Make those `24(%rbp)` and `16(%rbp)`.

Finally, you need to make sure the stack is aligned to 16 bytes when you call `printf`.  Library functions behave unpredictably when it's not.  Sometimes they may happen not to do anything that requires alignment and them everything appears to work; other times they may crash.

Comment: I've changed that line, but the segfault remains.

Comment: @AlexF: But I think you'll find it's not the same segfault - the call now goes to `f0` as it should, at least in my test.  So you've fixed that bug and can now move on to your next bug.

Comment: I see. Now it doesn't segfault, but prints `12596322`? Hmm...

Comment: The final problem wasn't the stack alignment, but that my stack offsets were wrong - they should've been 16 and 24, not 8 and 16. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @AlexF: Also note that `mov $f0, %rax` only works in non-PIE code (because it uses a 32-bit absolute address).  Use `lea f0(%rip), %rax` to put an address in a register.  [How to load address of function or label into register in GNU Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012), unless you're optimizing for non-PIE on purpose, then use `mov $f0, %eax` (32-bit operand-size = smaller instruction), or in your case `push $f0` since you ultimately need the value on the stack, not in a register, it seems. I'm sure you realize that your toy compiler's code-gen is at this point very inefficient :P

Comment: @Peter Cordes I'm fully aware that it's inefficient. This is just a toy, and there are exactly zero optimizations being done at the moment. I'm generating this way because it lets me do first-class functions easily in the compiler. About the PIE thing, I already have to compile with `-no-pie` on GCC to get it to work on my machine. Not really sure what the flag does though.

Comment: @AlexF: no-pie makes a traditional position-*dependent* ELF executable that isn't ASLRed at load time.  Static addresses are a link-time constant, and are in the low 2GiB of virtual address space so can be used as 32-bit immediates (sign- or zero-extended to 32-bit).  [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427).  I know you're not intentionally optimizing anything at this point, but `mov $f0, %rax` has zero advantages; nobody should ever do that except for a non-PIE kernel that loads in the high 2GiB (can sign but not zero extend addrs).

Comment: @PeterCordes nvm, I figured out how to compile without `-no-pie` using rip-relative addressing for the format string for printf (although there may be a better way, but that's more of a Code Review question than a SO one.) Thanks for your advice and links!